# I need to change the toggle switches in GridToolbarColumnsButton(DataGrid subcomponent in MUI) to check boxes

Tags: css, reactjs, checkbox, material-ui, datagrid

I'm working on a website in which a page had table data in which the data is coming from backend for filtering for that table I've used Mui filters from datagrid({...data}components={{ toolbar: CustomToolbar }}),one of those is a GridToolbarColumnsButton filter which I uploaded the pic here I need "checkboxes" instead of those switches what should I do for that?

I have tried using inspect elements and using:

```
componentsProps={{
    panel: {

      sx: {
        '& .MuiPopper-root': {
          // color: 'red',
          fontSize: 15,
          backgroundColor:'red'
        },
       }
     }
   }}
```

This code inside datagrid for overriding but it can't happen

Answer (score 0):

*There is no straight forward way to override GridToolbarColumnsButton as of Data Grid version v6.13.0.*

**We can achieve the same with the help of api reference **useGridApiContext** as I did below,**

**Output:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghCPz.png)

*(I have skipped import statements, please add it...)*
**CustomPopupCheckboxes:**

```
export default function CustomPopupCheckboxes(props) {
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();

  const [visibleColumns, setVisibleColumns] = useState([]);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(apiRef.current.getVisibleColumns());

  useEffect(() => {
    setVisibleColumns(apiRef.current.getVisibleColumns());
  });

  return (
    <Menu
      id="long-menu"
      anchorEl={props.moreMenuAnchorEl}
      open={props.openColumnsMenu}
      onClose={() => props.setOpenColumnsMenu(!props.openColumnsMenu)}
    >
      {columns.map((column) => {
        let isVisible = visibleColumns.filter((x) => x.field == column.field);
        return (
          <div style={column.hideable ? {} : { display: "none" }}>
            <Checkbox
              checked={isVisible.length != 0 ? true : false}
              onChange={(e) => {
                apiRef.current.setColumnVisibility(
                  column.field,
                  e.target.checked
                );
                setVisibleColumns(apiRef.current.getVisibleColumns());
              }}
            />
            {column.headerName}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </Menu>
  );
}
```

**CustomToolbar:**

```
export default function CustomToolbar(props) {
  const [openColumnsMenu, setOpenColumnsMenu] = useState(false);
  const [columnsMenuAnchorEl, setColumnsMenuAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  return (
    <GridToolbarContainer
      style={{
        display: "inline-block",
        textAlign: "right",
        marginBottom: "10px",
      }}
    >
        <CustomIconButton
          onClick={(event) => {
            setOpenColumnsMenu(!openColumnsMenu);
            setColumnsMenuAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
          }}
        >
          <img src="./Icons/Columns.svg" />
        </CustomIconButton>
        <CustomPopupCheckboxes
          moreMenuAnchorEl={columnsMenuAnchorEl}
          openColumnsMenu={openColumnsMenu}
          setOpenColumnsMenu={(value) => setOpenColumnsMenu(value)}
        />
      </div>
    </GridToolbarContainer>
  );
}
```

In my scenario, I had to create IconButton and after click on that button I had to open a popup with checkboxes.